# what represents this strange matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, quaternions

But I just encountered a very strange type of matrix.

[image]

What is the name of this type of matrix? How can it be solved?
The final result should be a $4\times 4$ matrix, but I only see $5$ elements on very strange places in this matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $K$ is written as a [block matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix), which means that the four entries you see are actually other matrices (of differing dimensions).

So $\sigma$ is just a number (in whatever field you're working over), i.e., a $1\times 1$ matrix. $Z$ is the $3\times 1$ matrix listed there and $Z^T$ is the transpose: a $1\times 3$ matrix. This leaves $S-\sigma I = B+B^T-\sigma I$. From the context (or reading the paper), we can infer that $B$  must be a $3\times 3$ matrix and $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

Something like $$K=\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}{s_{1,1}-\sigma} &\color{red}{s_{1,2}} & \color{red}{s_{1,3}} & \color{blue}{z_1}\\ \color{red}{s_{2,1}} & \color{red}{s_{2,2}-\sigma} & \color{red}{s_{2,3}} & \color{blue}{z_2}\\ \color{red}{s_{3,1}} & \color{red}{s_{3,2}} & \color{red}{s_{3,3}-\sigma} & \color{blue}{z_3}\\ \color{blue}{z_1} & \color{blue}{z_2} & \color{blue}{z_3} & \sigma\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: what about "tr[B]"? Do you know what his means?

Comment: Yes that's just the trace of $B$ (sum of the diagonal entries)

Comment: Why is the sign sigma there if B is a 3x3 matrix? By multiplying Vkb and Vki you get your 3x3 matrix. I think this sigma means you have to add up the value of every cell of the matrix. But this would make no sense for the rest...

Comment: I think in this section you have $N$ pairs of $3\times 1$ vectors $(v_{1b},v_{1i}),(v_{2b},v_{2i}),\ldots, (v_{Nb},v_{Ni})$. So for each $k=1,2,...,N$, the product $v_{kb}v_{ki}^T$ results in a $3\times 3$ matrix, and then you are adding up (scalar multiples of) all these matrices.

Comment: Knowing a cross product of 2 vectors gives you a third vector which is orhtogonal. What does this 3x3 matrix actually represent? (in all cases not a vector I think)

Comment: @triloli Not sure I understand. I don't see anything having to do with a cross product appearing in your question. Maybe it is related, but I have no idea what paper you're reading or where the matrix in your original question is coming from.